Unable to read docx file using python-docx
I have this code:
import os
import traceback

import pdfplumber
from docx import Document

def read_docx(file_path):
    try:
        doc = Document(file_path)
        content = [paragraph.text for paragraph in doc.paragraphs]
        return '\n'.join(content)
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error reading DOCX file: {e}"

def read_pdf(file_path):
    try:
        text = ''
        with pdfplumber.open(file_path) as pdf:
            for page in pdf.pages:
                text += page.extract_text() or ''
        return text
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error reading PDF file: {e}"

def read_txt(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            return file.read()
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error reading TXT file: {e}"

def read_file(folder_path, patent_name=None, file_name=None):
    if file_name:
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, patent_name, file_name)
    elif patent_name:
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, patent_name)
    else:
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path)

    if os.path.basename(file_path).startswith('~$'):
        return "Skipping temporary file."

    if file_path.endswith('.docx'):
        return read_docx(file_path)
    elif file_path.endswith('.pdf'):
        return read_pdf(file_path)
    elif file_path.endswith('.txt') and file_name:
        return read_txt(file_path)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unsupported file format or missing file name for .txt file")

def save_text_to_file(folder_path, text, patent_name, file_name):
    try:
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, patent_name)
        if not os.path.exists(file_path):
            os.makedirs(file_path)
        with open(os.path.join(file_path, file_name), "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(text)
    except Exception as err:
        print(err, traceback.format_exc())

For some reason, I am able to read all of the docx files except one. The files are read on the basis of docID. Here's the structure of docID:
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        16/04/2024     18:00                custom_template
-a----        16/04/2024     17:48         162129 input_disclosure.docx

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        16/04/2024     17:47          39928 input_customTemplate.docx

Here's the error that I am getting:
raise PackageNotFoundError("Package not found at '%s'" % pkg_file)
docx.opc.exceptions.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at 'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Projects\PatentGenie\temp\234\custom_template\~$put_customTemplate.docx'

Note:

I haven't opened the file on MS Word or any other editor during execution.
All other files are getting read except this one.
I have copied and pasted the file by manually creating the directory; still no luck.
I have also changed the content inside of the file (by adding couple of spaces) still no luck.
I have also made a new file with the same name. Used the 'Save As' method. Still no luck.


based on the error it seems like the file itself is either a deleted file (and only a remnant ~$put_customTemplate.docx) or is a version of a opened file (such as when you open the file manually) which likely doesn't have any content and is just a boot into the real file.

error shows path with ~$  - so it seems doesn't work your line if os.path.basename(file_path).startswith('~$'): return "Skipping temporary file."

Should I just clear my WIndows temp directory to clear off the cache and check out if it runs? (@AndrewRyan)

Yea, I saw that @furas. Thank you for pointing it out. Let me try to fix the logic and execute it once again.

Hey guys,
Yes it was an issue with Windows. I ran the same files and code on Linux and they worked. Guess I need to switch to Linux to escape these issue :')

Cleared up temp and appdata files of MS Word and the code worked.
